# Why is data showing for Views but not Total Users?

Tags: looker-studio

I've set up a simple graph in Looker Studio for a particular landing page.

The issue is that while the Views metric does show data, Total Users does not. When using a scorecard, Total Users does show data.

[Report 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQIM4.png)

To add further confusion, replicating this scorecard in a second report results in no data. There are no issues with the filter and data source. Both reports use the exact same settings.

[Report 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJMzL.png)

What are some possible explanations for this? I'm unsure of how to tackle this error from here.

I tried creating a second report to see if this is a bug. Not knowing what was going to happen, the second report gave me further confusion.

Comment: unfortunately you are not providing enough information  for someone to help you, there could be many reasons why this has happened.  My first step to debugging would be to create a table with date and both views and users, this will show you if its a data issue. If data is in the table convert the table to a graph and see if the data disappears, this will tell you if there is a challenge with the graph.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're missing a date dimension on the x-axis. Are you using a different data source from which the total user values are being drawn from? As someone else has suggested, I would also suggest to create a table with total users and a date as your two columns. If it works, perhaps instead of creating a new visualisation you could just change the chart type.